# Is Team Build 2012 compatible with Team Foundation Server 2010?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

What is the experience connecting [Team Build](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server#Team_Build) 2012 to a [Team Foundation Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) 2010?

We need to create a couple of more build agents, but Team Foundation Server will not be upgraded until a later time.

Answer (score 9):

Confirmed: this will not work.  You must upgrade TFS 2010 to 2012.  I received an error attempting to install a 2012 build service against TFS 2010:

*"The register command is not supported for Team Foundation Server [my server] because the server is not compatible."*

After upgrading TFS 2010 to 2012 it installed fine.  Note that upgrading TFS 2010 to 2012 means backing up your database, uninstalling 2010, installing 2012, and then choosing "Upgrade" from the Configuration Center.

Answer (score 2):

It does now, since Update 2 was released April 2013 :) See Martin Hinselwood's post: [Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 supports 2010 Build Servers](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/visual-studio-2012-update-2-supports-2010-build-servers/).

Comment: The question was the other way around. Connecting a 2012 build controller to a 2010 team foundation server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for certain but I'm resonably sure that this won't work. You should create new TFS 2010 build agents and then upgrade the build agents at the same time you upgrade the TFS server.

You should be able to install the 2 build agent versions "side by side" and disable the 2012 service until you've upgraded the TFS server. We've done this in the past when upgrading from TFS 2008 - 2010. When you upgrade the TFS server you can diable the 2010 service and enable the 2012 service.